# iOS custom tag for UIButton

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, tags, uibutton

Since I have many buttons that call the same target method I need to store additional information to every UIButton. Integer tag is not enough for me as I need to save at least  two integers values.

I have many buttons with the same target:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Then I can get a sender tag:

```
[((UIButton *) senter) tag];
```

I have NSDictionary with some values. Depending on what button have been pressed I need to change the value in NSDictionary. NSDictionary consists of row, which consists of rows, which consists of a columns. I need to know the indexes of elements to change, that is why I need to save a custom tag, that should contain index of row, index of subrow, index of column and so on.

I'm thinking which approach to select:

1. Parse integer tag into NSString, then split this string into a parts.
2. Create a custom UIButton class which allow to store the tag as
       object.
3. Create a custom UIButton class which contains few variables for my
   needs.

Or even you can suggest the better approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tag is only for getting particular button identifier that u get selected button at same method. so you can set additional info at the method with relevant button.

Comment: Create a custom UIButton class which allow to store the tag as object. this approach is best don't west time go for it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate/share why you need 2 integer values ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a Unique Pattern in the form of Number. You can create different patterns for different purposes and then you can merge all these patterns into a single pattern which itself will be a number and then you can save it as a **tag**.

**For Example**, you can convert the time say of **12** Hours **37** Minutes and **20** Seconds into **123720** which is a number itself and then you can use it as **tag**.

Here, your button tag contains the *variables* (Hours, Minutes and Seconds) of your needs.

You can get the value of button tag by : `yourButton.tag`. Then as you mentioned, you can *split the value of tag* and get all the *variables*.

**Update :**

It looks like you have a *table* kind of pattern and in each *cell* of *table*, you have some element that you want to make uniquely identified.

So, you will be needed *row number* and *column number* to make that element unique. In that case you can use the pattern like `(rownumber)(colnumber)`.

**For Example**, `tag = 0503` will give you the component at the 5th Row and on the 3rd Column.

There is nothing wrong with this way. You can use it.

Comment: That's how it works now. I'm converting it to integer pattern and then splitting it. But I think that this is no the most advanced solution and it is better to change to custom UIButton class.

Comment: @user2146071 : What's your purpose behind doing this ?

Comment: I think that access to the field of the class is much faster than parsing and splitting values.

Comment: @user2146071 : I am not getting what you want to say by *"field of the class"*. But there is nothing here (in setting/getting tag values) that may slower your execution. You can simply use this method and I am quite sure that it will work.

Comment: I will accept it in a few days, as it only the one answer. It didn't help me, really. I'm new to iOS, but as from Java, the performance of splitting the String or making a subString, or even accessing to an element of array is much slower than just accessing the field of the class (by the field of the class I mean: creating an object of the class and then setting and getting variables from it).

Comment: @user2146071: But, you are not getting the meaning of **tag**. You are trying to make it more complicated for yourself. The Answer is so simple - as i mentioned in my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the intended purpose of a view tag (or you understand it, and are trying to abuse it :) ). The tag is simply meant to be used to identify one view from another, the actual value isn't intended to be used for anything (or much); it certainly isn't intended to store some part of your model.

If you use the tag property to identify which button was pressed, you can then perform the appropriate logic.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?